# DOTNET Visual RPG - ASNA - ASP

Tags: asp.net, asna-visual-rpg

I'm a long time RPG and web developer (Java and PHP) but not VRPG

Does anyone know how to store a packed decimal array in a session and then retrieve it. Sounds trivial but I can't get it to work.

something like:

```
DclArray test type(*packed) *len(8,0) dim(22)
Session("save") = test
```

Then on button click retrieve it

```
test = Session("save) *as Array
```

This works fine with strings and other classes but not arrays. Obviously something wrong with my syntax.

Comment: Does VRPG use VB based ASP.NET or C# based?

Comment: Neither, it is used instead of those.

Comment: Oh, ok it is a separate language.

Comment: The answer as supplied by ASNA is Session("save") *as system.decimal[]

Comment: And that code doesn't work? Arrays typically aren't classes. The "system.decimal[]" sounds right because that is declaring a decimal array.